# How to insert data into a binary tree in level order?

Tags: java, binary-tree, insertion, insertion-order

As the title suggests, I am currently trying to construct a binary tree wherein user inputs are inserted in in-level order. Almost all of the tutorials and implementations in Java that I've read uses a sorted method of insertion.

I've tried gfg's method, but it uses queues, which resulted me being graded 0.

gfg method:

```
void addData(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } else {
        Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(root);

        while (true) {
            Node node = queue.remove();

            if (node.left != null && node.right != null) {
                queue.add(node.left);
                queue.add(node.right);
            }
            else {
                if (node.left == null) {
                    node.left = newNode;
                    queue.add(node.left);
                } else {
                    node.right = newNode;
                    queue.add(node.right);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Output (In-order): 4 2 5 1 6 3 7 (Correct, but as mentioned it uses queues)

The insertion that I understand w/o queues (but this one sorts user input):

```
private Node insertNode(Node current, int data) {
    if (current == null) {
        return new Node(data);
    }

    if (data < current.data) {
        current.left = insertNode(current.left, data);
    }
    else if (data > current.data) {
        current.right = insertNode(current.right, data);
    }
    else {
        return current;
    }

    return current;
}

public void addNode(int data) {
    root = insertNode(root, data);
}
```

Input: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Output (In-Order): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

To note, yes, I've also tried to implement gfg's method to what I understand. But I personally cannot make it make sense? I'm really stuck.

Edit:
The whole code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryTree {
    static class Node {
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            right = left = null;
        }
    }

    public static class treeBinary {
        Node root;

        treeBinary() {
            root = null;
        }

        private Node insertNode(Node current, int data) {
            if (current == null) {
                return new Node(data);
            }

            if (data < current.data) {
                current.left = insertNode(current.left, data);
            }
            else if (data > current.data) {
                current.right = insertNode(current.right, data);
            }
            else {
                return current;
            }

            return current;
        }

        public void addNode(int data) {
            root = insertNode(root, data);
        }

        public void inorderPrint(Node node) {
            if (node != null) {
                inorderPrint(node.left);
                System.out.print(" " + node.data);
                inorderPrint(node.right);
            }
        }

        void inorderPrint() {
            inorderPrint(root);
        }

        public void preorderPrint(Node node) {
            if (node != null) {
                System.out.print(" " + node.data);
                preorderPrint(node.left);
                preorderPrint(node.right);
            }
        }

        void preorderPrint() {
            preorderPrint(root);
        }

        public void postorderPrint(Node node) {
            if (node != null) {
                postorderPrint(node.left);
                postorderPrint(node.right);
                System.out.print(" " + node.data);
            }
        }

        void postorderPrint() {
            postorderPrint(root);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputUser = new Scanner(System.in);
        treeBinary userBT = new treeBinary();
        boolean userChoice = false;
        int count = 0;

        mainMenu:
        do {
            System.out.println("\n\n\n1 - Add Data");
            System.out.println("2 - Print (In-Order)");
            System.out.println("3 - Print (Pre-Order");
            System.out.println("4 - Print (Post-Order)");
            System.out.println("5 - Exit");

            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            switch (inputUser.nextInt()) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("How many will you input? ");
                    int x = inputUser.nextInt();

                    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                        System.out.print("Input Data " + (count+1) + ": ");
                        userBT.addNode(inputUser.nextInt());
                        count++;
                    }

                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("The Tree in In-Order: ");
                    userBT.inorderPrint();

                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("The Tree in Pre-Order: ");
                    userBT.preorderPrint();

                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("The Tree in Post-Order: ");
                    userBT.postorderPrint();

                    break;

                case 5:
                    break mainMenu;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input!");
            }
        }
        while (!userChoice);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I've tried gfg's method, but it uses queues, which resulted me being graded 0."*: level order implies the use of a queue. You should include more explanation as to why that approach is not the one you need. Saying that you got a grade of 0 is not an explanation. There so many reasons why another implementation was expected from you, but then that information is lacking from your question. BTW *in-level order* is not a thing. Either it is *in-order* or *level order*, which are different orders.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. Further explanation regarding the marks that the whole class got: We were asked to imitate the given tree, others tried inserting user input data by comparing (the traditional way, lower to the left, higher to the right) which was marked as wrong and others like me did insertion in level order, which produced the right output but was wrong as I've said in the post. We've tried to find other alternatives, but we're already at wit's end since almost all resources points to a comparative method of insertion from user input. Sorry, I just dont want this to happen again

Comment: I don't really see an explanation of the marks you got. You have explained what people have tried and submitted, but not what the reason is for the assessment. Can you quote the assignment literally so we have complete information on what is expected?

Comment: the tree needs to look like this: [img](https://ibb.co/xF7qwnP) then we need traverse it inorder, preorder, and postorder . Also we weren't told the reason of why we are all wrong, so everyone is scrapping every bit of resources in google. Because the data should be user inputs and the tree must not be constructed manually (eg. tree.root.left.right).

Comment: So you are not asked to first create an empty tree and then process input as it comes and insert it in the tree? It would really be helpful if you could literally quote the assignment, word for word. This avoids misunderstanding.

Comment: The Task: "Solve the problem using Java, Create a program for this [Tree](https://ibb.co/xF7qwnP) and display outputs of traversing the tree, inorder, preorder, and postorder." Additional unwritten but said notes: the tree must be constructed within the program, not within the code.

Comment: *"Create a program for this Tree"* is unclear. A tree can be implemented in many ways. For instance, the depicted tree could be implemented as an ArrayList, without any Node class, since it happens to be a min-heap. And that is just one of many ways to do it. It is not clear whether that imaged tree is just an example or it should really be **that** tree only. *"within the program, not within the code"* makes no sense: program and code are virtually synonyms. I note that nothing is said about user input. Without much more clarification I'm afraid I cannot help you.

Comment: Having to insert in some particular order seems like a ridiculous requirement.  The tree **provides** the order; trees are used for sorting, amongst other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days and hours of trying and reading. I applied the idea of balancing the tree from the user's inputs instead of inserting in comparison with the previous input data. Personally, I don't know if this is what the professor is looking for, but I'll try and try. Thanks @trincot

Here is what I've came up with, just a mishmash of everything that I've read and watched, nothing original:

```
    public static class treeBinary {

        boolean checkBal(int countSide) {
            countSide = countSide + 1;

            while (countSide % 2 == 0) {
                countSide = countSide / 2;
            }

            if (countSide == 1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        Node insertData(Node root, int data) {
            if (root == null) {
                Node newNode = new Node(data);
                return newNode;
            }

            if (root.rightSide == root.leftSide) {
                root.left = insertData(root.left, data);
                root.leftSide++;
            }
            else if (root.rightSide < root.leftSide) {
                if (checkBal(root.leftSide)) {
                    root.right = insertData(root.right, data);
                    root.rightSide++;
                }
                else {
                    root.left = insertData(root.left, data);
                    root.leftSide++;
                }
            }

            return root;
        }

        void inorderPrint(Node node) {
            if (node != null) {
                inorderPrint(node.left);
                System.out.print(node.data + " ");
                inorderPrint(node.right);
            }

        }
    }
```

I'll try to refine even more to the extent of my knowledge as a learning student.